# Unwanted extra [" "] in Hash value on Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if I do something wrong here.

here is the ruby 1.9.2 code that I have just upgraded from 1.8.6

```
def prepares_data(hash_nodes)
    @array_of_node = Array.new
    hash_nodes.each do | node |
      nodeId = node.values_at('self')[0].split('/').last
      text = node.values_at('data')[0].values_at('name')
      puts text
      @array_of_node << { :nodeId => nodeId, :text => text } 
    end
    puts @array_of_node
    return @array_of_node
  end
```

So basically, the code just adda bunch of Hash to Array which is all fine. When I print text inside the loop I also get plain text result

```
What allergies do you have?
What dont you like?
What is your specific diet?
```

However, when I print out @array_of_node I get this

```
{:nodeId=>"7", :text=>["What allergies do you have?"]}
{:nodeId=>"8", :text=>["What dont you like?"]}
{:nodeId=>"9", :text=>["What is your specific diet?"]}
```

In the text I have extra ["..."] which I don't want. How do I get rid of that, and I really don't understand this part, because this code worked fine in ruby 1.8.7. Did I do something wrong here?

Thank you so much.

Comment: is line in your code '@array_of_node  nodeId, :text => text }' right?

Comment: Sorry it should be @array_of_node << { :nodeId => nodeId, :text => text }

Comment: It is right, but it showed incorrectly in this post.

Comment: Instead of using `puts` how about `p`?

Comment: yes, try to inspect value using 'p text', if it is an array?

Comment: Idiomatic Ruby would use `@array_of_nodes = hash_nodes.map ... { :nodeId => nodeId, :text => text } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values_at method returns an array, so I think that's why it's happening. Try passing a key instead like this:

```
text = node.values_at('data')[0]['name']
```

Comment: Note the difference in Array.to_s between 1.8 and 1.9! 1.8 used to do a self.join, while 1.9 aliases to_s to inspect, so it outputs the array including quotes and the square brackets. Relying on the to_s method to get String output of an array is not clean. So the switch to 1.9 helps you find unclean uses of Arrays.

Been there as well ;).